# Are there any 2-way template to object libraries?

Tags: java, xml, templates

We frequently use templates as a way of serializing an object. That is, given a Java POJO and a suitable XML template that includes placeholders like ${person.address.street}, we can output fully formed XML etc.

Are there any libraries where you can take that same template and a sample piece of output, and go the other way? That is, produce a populated Java bean (for instance) from a template, a sample XML document and, I guess, a Class name.

Comment: Does it have to be an XML _template,_ or any customizable automatic XML generation library? If the latter, look at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) or even [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/).

Comment: Looking for something template based. I'm well aware of XStream and JAXB, and would prefer to not go down that route. They both work well where the XML and object mapping are similar, but get cumbersome when the two are more disparate (i.e. when using XStream aliases).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Freemarker to help you it's a great JAVA API[image]

You can have XML template file which call getters and then create a dynamic XML file.

Tell me if it's helps,

Comment: No, that's not what I'm looking for. I know you can use freemarker to create the XML output (and I actually am in this case). I'm looking for a library that ALSO lets you take the template and output and produce the Java objects from them i.e. go in the other direction.